# plug in value to evaluate expression with variable - r

Tags: r

I have a df with a column containing an expression that has 1-3 variables. The variable values are contained in a variable that has the same name of the variable in the expression.

I would like to calculate the value of that expression, for example

```
    X=5 
    df[1,1]
    result=calculate(X,15.057719-26.5963*X+22.13*X^2)
```

I want to evaluate the above expression with the value contained in X and store the result in a variable.

edit: the problem is that the equation changes for every row in the data frame, so I can't really create a function for each equation.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a UDF to do this. An example of this is below

```
calculate <- function(X){
returnval <- 15.057719-26.5963*X+22.13*X^2
returnval
}

result <- calculate(10)
```

Comment: thanks, the problem is that the equation changes for every row in the data frame, so I can't really create a function for each equation.

Comment: Could you post a more complete, reproducible example then, so we can fully understand the issue?